# Lazy Loading without adding route segment for module

Tags: angular, routes, lazy-loading

To implement Lazy Loading in Angular app, we need to add module route / main page (/public/) and then inner page route(/contact-us) like

```
{ path: 'public', loadChildren: '../public/public.module#PublicModule' }
```

and inside PublicRouting

```
{ path: 'contact-us', component: ContactUsComponent }
```

now for ContactUs component we have url like http://myappurl/public/contact-us . But I want to implement Lazy Loading and also need to access page with link like http://myappurl/contact-us so that my SEO things works as expected. I don't want to make each page as module and my modules have multiple pages

Comment: it looks like you want one more parent route which is in child routes module right?

Comment: what about the other routes which are in public modules those should be loaded like  http://myappurl/public/other-routes ?

Comment: I simply want to load module inner page directly like myappurl.com/contact-us , and other inner pages of same module myappurl.com/faqs etc

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve this: http://myappurl/contact-us

Replace `public` with  '' in the module routing

```
{ path: '', loadChildren: '../public/public.module#PublicModule' }
```

then do not change anything else

Or :

Replace `public` with  'contact-us' in the module routing

```
  { path: 'contact-us', loadChildren: '../public/public.module#PublicModule' }
```

and then inside the routing module of public.module

```
{ path: '', component: ContactUsComponent , pathMath:"full" }
```

Comment: If you have an empty path that is at the root of your routing, you do not need to lazy loaed it, since it will be the first thing that loads and is displayed to the user. If you get rid of the "public" part of your URL, then you should lazy load the child modules one by one.

Comment: @AbolfazlR thanks, it works. I don't think it effect the lazy loading, right? (module should be load on demand, not at first load)

Comment: @Maryannah I need to lazy load, don't want to load resources used by inner pages initially when app loaded (with home page)

Comment: **THIS** is your homepage. If you remove the path, it becomes the main route, and if you lazy load it, you're just increasing the resources needed by your application. As for the second solution provided, it's a very bad practice and will result in headaches and errors.

Comment: I'm not going for 2nd part, I just used like { path: '', loadChildren: '../public/public.module#PublicModule' } and inside module routing { path: 'contact-us', component: ContactUsComponent }. Works fine for url segment, how can I verify if app loading ContactUsComponent resources on first load or not? it just need to load when I access it myappurl.com/contact-us.

Comment: @Bilal Ameer  - You can install this extension in google chrome to see what is happening:  https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/augury/elgalmkoelokbchhkhacckoklkejnhcd?hl=en

Comment: @Bilal Ameer - With this Extension
, you can see the list of the modules/component and ...  that are loaded

Comment: @AbolfazlR Thanks for extension, checked and it works as expected

Answer (score -1):

This might be your required solution:

Replace `public` with `` in module path

i.e. `{ path: '', loadChildren: '../public/public.module#PublicModule' }`

and let everything remain same.

So, your final path will be `http://myappurl/contact-us`

As you need not to specifically mention `public` in route, you will automatically redirected to this path.

Comment: application doesn't work, showing blank, no error in console. Did you try this?

Comment: This will work, if your app have some parent module outside `PublicModule` as well

Comment: Even it successfully built for prod, but app not working with this

Comment: then try replace it with ' ' instead of ' / '

Comment: You mean PublicModule should be child of another module, can you explain?

Comment: I don't know what is structure of your project.
But this should should work..
can you please share code somehow